# keep the size of array in a document less than or equal to 9

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using Firestore and have users documents with images array.  I am able to add / delete images from the images array without any problem. Both add and delete operations to the array are considered update to the user document. I would like to have an update security rule such that I can't have more than 9 images.

I am using the following rule:

```
allow update: if resource.data.images.size() < 9
```

As soon as I have nine images in the array, I am no longer able to delete an image.  So the rule is conflicting for add and remove.  What is the best way to handle this.  I appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resource.data` contains the fields in the document that currently exist.  `request.resource.data` contains the fields that are about to be written by the client app.  You will want to use the latter to check the incoming fields rather than the existing fields.

```
allow update: if request.resource.data.images.size() < 9
```